# file_get_contents with Lumen

Tags: php, laravel, file-get-contents, lumen

I have this code into a function (php class) :

```
$theFile = '/test/test.xml'; // these are in the public folder
dd(file_get_contents($theFile));
```

If I go to `mydomain.local/test/test.xml`, I get the working xml code.

But with `file_get_contents`, I get this error :

```
file_get_contents(/test/test.xml): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

How to solve this ?

Comment: `file_get_contents()` executed relatively to your php script (and you won't fiddle much where the real code being executed right, cause how laravel works) if you had that path. use `base_path() . '/test/test.xml'`.

Comment: @Tezla this doesn't work

Comment: dang, why don't you read the [docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/helpers#method-public-path), it it's in public path you could `public_path('test/test.xml')`. just to be sure, to `dd` this code and look the path - if it's correct, it's your answer. otherwise, good luck :) - and obviously, my earlier comment wont work, i assume test directory were on the root along with `app`, `config`, ..., `vendor`.

Comment: Thank you. I had a little hope of a sudden ... I use Lumen and `public_path()` is not implemented in this framework, for the moment (Lumen 5.1.6)

Comment: my bad, [lumen had no such support](http://lumen.laravel.com/docs/installation)

Comment: @Tezla Thank you anyway for your comments. You learn me some things, if I decide to switch to Laravel ;)

Comment: try file path: `$theFile = './test/test.xml';`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Lumen doesn't have the `public_path()` that you might be familiar with in Laravel to easily grab the path to a public file.

The simplest method for re-implementing it would be to add a package called [irazasyed/larasupport](https://github.com/irazasyed/larasupport) to your project which adds various missing helpers (including `public_path()`) as well as adding the vendor publish command that is missing from Lumen.

Alternatively if you do not wish to add a third party package simply create a file in your app directory called `helpers.php` and then within your `composer.json` file add the following within the "autoload" part and run `composer dump-autoload` to refresh the autoloader cache:

```
"files": [
    "app/helpers.php"
],
```

Then within `helpers.php` add the following content:

```
<?php
if (!function_exists('public_path')) {
   /**
    * Get the path to the public folder.
    *
    * @param  string $path
    * @return string
    */
    function public_path($path = '')
    {
        return env('PUBLIC_PATH', base_path('public')) . ($path ? '/' . $path : $path);
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent answer ! I opted for the [irazasyed](https://packagist.org/packages/irazasyed/larasupport) solution that is safer in my opinion

Comment: @Zl3n how do you know it's safer? It might be using the same thing. I guess it does pretty much the same thing [here](https://github.com/irazasyed/larasupport/blob/master/src/helpers.php)

Comment: Shouldn't the autoload string be changed to "helpers.php" removing the app as composer.json resides in app?

Answer (score 2):

You are passing an absolute path to the function that is relative to the server's base directory. This is not necessary the same base directory for the URL. Try passing a path relative to the current executing script.