# Lumen read JSON from file

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I'm using `Lumen Framework` and I'm trying to seed my database from a `json` file. I'm doing something like this:

```
public function run()
{
    $json = json_decode(file_get_contents('database/seed/file.json'), true);
    ...
}
```

But when I do the seed command `php artisan db:seed`, I get this error:

> [ErrorException]
>
> file_get_contents(database/seed/file.json): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

I tried to do that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34201616/3701102 and I got this:

> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]
>
> Call to undefined function public_path()

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: Try to use `__DIR__` directive instead of relative path.

Comment: Have you created another directory called `seed` or does file.json exists in the `seeds` directory?

Comment: @RossWilson yes I did, first I tried with only `file.json`, then I tried with the route where the file is on the project

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Figure out the script path using `__DIR__`

```
public function run()
{
    dd(__DIR__);
}
```

For this example, lets say the output was `/home/vagrant/Code/app/Http/Controllers`.

Now this should work (if file permissions are proper)

```
public function run()
{
    $file_path = realpath(__DIR__ . '/../../database/seed/file.json');
    $json = json_decode(file_get_contents($file_path), true);
    // ...
}
```